# Same width dropdown for each link

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been searching and trying out some code to make my dropdown menu same size for each link, like nelly.se, but I can't figure that out. I was tried this code:

```
.nav-dropdown{position:fixed; left:0; right:0;}
```

but can't make it work at all.

The website I am working on is: http://94.247.169.169/~welloteket/

Comment: Include the code in your post please.

Comment: .nav-dropdown{position:fixed; left:0; right:0;} but it gets totally wrong

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` will really fix it in relation to the window, which means it can't be scrolled at all - that won't work.

Usually for dropdowns you use `position: absolute` and adjust the `left` and `top settings as needed`. There are at least two important additional things:

1.) it has to be a direct child element of the element in relation to which you want it to fix. In the example you linked to that would be the black navigation bar, probably a `ul` element in there.

2.) That parent container has to have `position: relative`.

The kind of "mega dropdown"  (i.e. equal size and position for each dropdown regardless of its related main menu entry) is trickier than a regular dropdown (i.e. one than opens directly under / next to its main menu entry). You propably need Javascript for this.

Apart from those general guidelines we can only help you if you post detailed code - HTML, CSS and JS, if there is any.